# how to scroll collection view section item to horizontal using storyboard

Tags: xcode, view, collections

I am trying to scroll in horizontal of a collection view section item.
There may be multiple section in collection view.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this method?

```
-(void)scrollToItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Or, besides scrolling to item, you can scrollRectToVisible:sectionRect. This example scrolls to a first item in a given section also considering the header view.

```
- (void)scrollToSection:(NSUInteger)section
{
    if ([self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] > 0) {

        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:section]];

        CGRect sectionRect = CGRectMake(0, attributes.frame.origin.y - 65, self.collectionView.frame.size.width, self.collectionView.frame.size.height); // 65 is height of the header view

        [self.collectionView scrollRectToVisible:sectionRect animated:YES];

    } else {

        NSLog(@"no cell to scroll to");
    }
}
```