# Scrolling to a specific collection view header (not cell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview with a an index view (a custom one since the apple one works only with UITableViews), this index view which is an UIControl subclass that calls a method when the "value changed" event is fired. 
Obviously, the called method scrolls the collection view to the section associated with the touched letter.
So, here is the implementation I have for this method :

```
- (IBAction)indexViewValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection: [sender currentIndex]];

    [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: indexPath atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated: NO];

    collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(collectionView.contentOffset.x, MAX(collectionView.contentOffset.y - [(UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)[collectionView collectionViewLayout] headerReferenceSize].height, 0));
}
```

The problem is that some cases are not working because of the contentOffset adjustment (last line). 
For example if the content below the concerned section is smaller than the collectionView, the header won't be at the top of the screen after the scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: call, which is normal, but I would like to prevent the contentOffset adjustment which is made at the next line of code. 
My problem is that I have no idea of how I can determine that the header is already visible and avoid this contentOffset adjustment.

I'm taking any idea :)

Comment: UICollectionView has a property visibleCells (array) which contains all current visible cells.

Comment: I want to scroll just over the section header, not over a cell

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to scroll collection view section item to horizontal using storyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346909/how-to-scroll-collection-view-section-item-to-horizontal-using-storyboard)

Comment: Mikael, you're right, I have the same issue with a vertical collection view, but in this case that does not matter. Thanks for pointing me this post.

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be only one header per section, scroll to the first item whose NSIndexPath item value is 0 and section value is the number of the target section.

There are several to search for those particular index path values. Here's one way:

```
[self.collectionView.visibleCells indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(__kindof UICollectionViewCell * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        BOOL result = ([self.collectionView indexPathForCell:obj].item == 0 && [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:obj].section == 2);
            // Scroll to item at [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:obj]
        stop = &result;
        return result;
    }];
```